# Drawing a Trendline from the previous lower high to the last lower high

Tags: pine-script

Please see below the script and image, as an example, for higher highs and lower lows.
[image]

The variable for lower high is: "_lh". On the chart, we can see lower highs showing up only after 5 bars (offset = -5), which is fine.
I was wondering how it is possible to draw a trendline from the previous lower high to the last lower high (with offset=-5) that just happened,
and add an alertcondition for it when the price crosses up?

I know that I should use the line.new() build-up fonction, but I couldn't figure out how to call the previous lower high.

Thank you

```
//@version=5
indicator("Lower Low trendlines", shorttitle = "Lower Low trendlines", overlay=true)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////// HIGHER HIGH LOWER LOW /////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © LonesomeThecolor.blue

//@version=5
//indicator('Higher High Lower Low Strategy', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)
lb = input.int(5, title='Left Bars', minval=1, group="Higher High Lower Low")
rb = input.int(5, title='Right Bars', minval=1, group="Higher High Lower Low")
//showsupres = input.bool(true, title='Support/Resistance', inline='srcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
showsup = input.bool(true, title="Support only", inline="srcol_sup", group="Higher High Lower Low")
showres = input.bool(true, title="Resistance only", inline="srcol_res", group="Higher High Lower Low")
supcol = input.color(color.lime, title='', inline="srcol_sup", group="Higher High Lower Low")
rescol = input.color(color.red, title='', inline="srcol_res", group="Higher High Lower Low")
srlinestyle = input.string(line.style_dotted, title='Line Style/Width', options=[line.style_solid, line.style_dashed, line.style_dotted], inline='style', group="Higher High Lower Low")
srlinewidth = input.int(3, title='', minval=1, maxval=5, inline='style', group="Higher High Lower Low")
//changebarcol = input.bool(true, title='Change Bar Color', inline='bcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
//bcolup = input.color(color.blue, title='', inline='bcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")
//bcoldn = input.color(color.black, title='', inline='bcol', group="Higher High Lower Low")

ph = ta.pivothigh(lb, rb)
pl = ta.pivotlow(lb, rb)

iff_1 = pl ? -1 : na  // Trend direction
hl = ph ? 1 : iff_1
iff_2 = pl ? pl : na  // similar to zigzag but may have multiple highs/lows
zz = ph ? ph : iff_2
valuewhen_1 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_2 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
zz := pl and hl == -1 and valuewhen_1 == -1 and pl > valuewhen_2 ? na : zz
valuewhen_3 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_4 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
zz := ph and hl == 1 and valuewhen_3 == 1 and ph < valuewhen_4 ? na : zz

valuewhen_5 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_6 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
hl := hl == -1 and valuewhen_5 == 1 and zz > valuewhen_6 ? na : hl
valuewhen_7 = ta.valuewhen(hl, hl, 1)
valuewhen_8 = ta.valuewhen(zz, zz, 1)
hl := hl == 1 and valuewhen_7 == -1 and zz < valuewhen_8 ? na : hl
zz := na(hl) ? na : zz

findprevious() =>  // finds previous three points (b, c, d, e)
    ehl = hl == 1 ? -1 : 1
    loc1 = 0.0
    loc2 = 0.0
    loc3 = 0.0
    loc4 = 0.0
    xx = 0
    for x = 1 to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc1 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc2 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl == 1 ? -1 : 1
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc3 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc4 := zz[x]
            break
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4]

float a = na
float b = na
float c = na
float d = na
float e = na
if not na(hl)
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4] = findprevious()
    a := zz
    b := loc1
    c := loc2
    d := loc3
    e := loc4
    e

_hh = zz and a > b and a > c and c > b and c > d
_ll = zz and a < b and a < c and c < b and c < d
_hl = zz and (a >= c and b > c and b > d and d > c and d > e or a < b and a > c and b < d)
_lh = zz and (a <= c and b < c and b < d and d < c and d < e or a > b and a < c and b > d)

plotshape(_hl, text='HL', title='Higher Low', style=shape.labelup, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.belowbar, offset=-rb)
plotshape(_hh, text='HH', title='Higher High', style=shape.labeldown, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.abovebar, offset=-rb)
plotshape(_ll, text='LL', title='Lower Low', style=shape.labelup, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.belowbar, offset=-rb)
plotshape(_lh, text='LH', title='Lower High', style=shape.labeldown, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.abovebar, offset=-rb)

float res = na
float sup = na
res := _lh ? zz : res[1]
sup := _hl ? zz : sup[1]

int trend = na
iff_3 = close < sup ? -1 : nz(trend[1])
trend := close > res ? 1 : iff_3

res := trend == 1 and _hh or trend == -1 and _lh ? zz : res
sup := trend == 1 and _hl or trend == -1 and _ll ? zz : sup
rechange = res != res[1]
suchange = sup != sup[1]

var line resline = na
var line supline = na
//if showsupres
//    if rechange
//        line.set_x2(resline, bar_index)
//        line.set_extend(resline, extend=extend.none)
//        resline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=res, x2=bar_index, y2=res, color=rescol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
//        resline
//
//    if suchange
//        line.set_x2(supline, bar_index)
//        line.set_extend(supline, extend=extend.none)
//        supline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=sup, x2=bar_index, y2=sup, color=supcol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
//        supline

if showres
    if rechange
        line.set_x2(resline, bar_index)
        line.set_extend(resline, extend=extend.none)
        resline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=res, x2=bar_index, y2=res, color=rescol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
        resline

if showsup
    if suchange
        line.set_x2(supline, bar_index)
        line.set_extend(supline, extend=extend.none)
        supline := line.new(x1=bar_index - rb, y1=sup, x2=bar_index, y2=sup, color=supcol, extend=extend.right, style=srlinestyle, width=srlinewidth)
        supline




//iff_4 = trend == 1 ? bcolup : bcoldn
//barcolor(color=changebarcol ? iff_4 : na)


///////////////////////////////////////
////////////// TRENDLINES /////////////
///////////////////////////////////////

// How could we draw a trendline from the previous lower high to the last lower high, and add an alertcondition for it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use arrays to store each pivots.

```
var pivots = array.new_float()
var pivotbars = array.new_int()
If(pivotlow)
   array.push(pivots, pivotlow)
   array.push(pivotbars, pivotbar)
```

And then you can access the pivots and pivot bars using array get method. Use them to fetch last two pivots and draw line.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I only have very limited knowledge of arrays. However, your suggestions are very helpful, and hopefully I will be able to do it in the future.